# Order of JSP page imports

Tags: jsp, jboss, jakarta-ee

Does the order of the imports in a JSP page matter? I have a JSP page that worked just fine in JBoss 4, but is not compiling in JBoss 6. These are the imports:

```
<%@ page import="com.at.enp.SecurityManager,
        com.at.enp.util.webUtil,
        com.at.vb.mod.fa.db.RPData.ResetOption,
        com.at.enp.modules.loyalty.MetricSetting,
        java.util.List,
        com.at.presentation.security.EFRightsGroup,
        com.at.enp.modules.loyalty.BonusPlanHandler,
        com.at.presentation.bean.ef.RewardType,
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat,
        com.at.util.*"%>
```

The offending import is :           com.at.vb.mod.fa.db.RPData.ResetOption
ResetOption is a public class inside of RPData. If I move the import down in the import list the page compiles just fine. I have no idea why that is making a difference. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, the order of import statements in a Java class does not matter, so it shouldn't matter in the JSP too. However, I've seen JVM bugs like [6431987](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6431987) and [6391197](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6391197) about import order (the former being the closest to your case). Could you be affected by such a bug?

Comment: Wow, nasty bug. I think IDE's auto-ordering of imports in **normal Java classes** has taken care that I've never seen this bug before. One more reason why scriptlets are treacherous ;)

Comment: @BalusC Can't agree more. And it's really a nasty one as the problem [may not occur under Eclipse](http://unimplemented.blogspot.com/2007/08/my-java-puzzle-does-order-of-import.html), causing big headache. I would just hate to loose time on that one.